# Getting values from LinkedList according to user input

Tags: java, if-statement, linked-list, user-input, contains

Facing some issues with my lab codes
I've done trouble shooting to find that both there's nothing wrong with my filereader/bufferedreaders, Vehicle method and LinkedList values

I'm found out that I'm having Problems getting the if statement to work 
I do not know How do I compare the current linkedlist data extracted from my file.txt using tokenizer to pass into given fields with userinput using if/else ?

Main method

```
package test6;


// import packages
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Lab6 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    // Declare variables for reading file 
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String inFile = "Vehicle_Records.txt";
    final String INPUT_PROMPT = "\nPlease enter the search word " + "that you would like to obtain more information on:";
    String line;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    // Declare variables to contain the record fields

   String group; 
   String brand; 
   String model; 
   double rate; 

    // Declare and instantiate a new LinkedList
   LinkedList<Vehicle> list = new LinkedList<Vehicle>();

    try {
        // Instantiate FileReader & BufferedReader objects
        fr = new FileReader(inFile);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //read a line from the file
        line = br.readLine();

        // While line is not null
        while (line != null) {
            // Tokenize the records
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            group = tokenizer.nextToken();
            brand = tokenizer.nextToken();
            model = tokenizer.nextToken();
            rate = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            // Create a new Vehicle object of the record
            Vehicle newVehicle = new Vehicle(group, brand, model, rate);
            System.out.println(newVehicle);
             // Add this item object into the LinkedList
            list.add(newVehicle);
            // Read another line from file
            line = br.readLine();

        }
        // Close BufferedReader
        br.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("The file" + inFile + "was not found");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Reading error!" + e);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        //Check if FileReader is opened
        if (fr != null) {
            try {
                //close FileReader
                fr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error closing file!");
            }
        }
    }
      // Print out the input prompt

        System.out.println(INPUT_PROMPT);

    try 
    {

       // Create readers to read from user input
        //FileReader ufr = new FileReader(INPUT_PROMPT);
        BufferedReader ubr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

       // Read one line from user input
       String uline=ubr.readLine();
        // Loop through all the records in the LinkedList

        for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++)
        {
        // if the record is the same as the input from user 
        // (Hint: use contains() in String class to check whether 
        // search word is found in the records
         String temp = new String(uline);

        if(list.get(i)== uline.contains(temp))
        {
            //print out the information of the vehicle that match user input
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }          


        }

    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Input error!" + e);
    }
    }
}//main
```

Vehical Class

```
package lab6;


public class Vehicle {
    // Declare all the variables to contain the fields of a record 
    String group; 
    String brand; 
    String model; 
    double rate; 
// Creates a constructor to store all the fields into the variables 
    public Vehicle(String group, String brand, String model, double rate) 
    { 
        this.group=group; this.brand=brand; this.model=model; this.rate=rate; 
    } 
// Create a toString() method to return string in the same delimited 
// format as the input record 
    public String toString() 
    { 
        return(group+","+brand+","+model+","+rate); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend some more time formatting your code - you expect others to spend their time to help you; so you should spend some time making that as easy as possible.

Comment: StringTokenizer is deprecated and shouldn't be used in any new code.

Comment: @David Conrad StringTokenizer is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: @Alex I mean deprecated in the English sense, in that everyone puts it down and says not to use it, although the official docs also say "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code."

Comment: @David Conrad, agree with you, it was some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not inside a method , so you are facing a problem.

Comment: Thou could learns't thy Java from here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: I did have a main method, I didn't declare the method in here as I overlooked it x) , by the way as said, I've done troubleshooting, the only reason my code's not generating any results is because my if statement is wrong.. I don't know how to make it compare user input to the variables stored in the linked list

Answer (score 0):

I assume since your looking through vehicle objects trying to find a match of one its four variables. Your approach is wrong since you're comparing an object with a String.

Instead you could use a [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface inside the Vehicle class where you would simply compare multiple strings.

**Edit:**

```
public class Vehicle implements Comparable<String>{

/* This method returns 0 if the search matches
 * Else it return a negative or a positive number*/
@Override
public int compareTo(String o) {
    int cmp = this.getBrand().compareToIgnoreCase(o);
    if(cmp == 0) return cmp;

    cmp = this.getGroup().compareToIgnoreCase(o);
    if(cmp == 0) return cmp;

    cmp = this.getModel().compareToIgnoreCase(o);
    if(cmp == 0) return cmp;
    /* Edited this part to work with doubles */
    try{
        cmp = (int)(this.getRate() - Double.parseDouble(o));
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return cmp;
    }

    return cmp;

}
}
```

And here is how you would loop through it:

```
for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).compareTo(uline) == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));

            }   
        }
```

Hope it help.

PS. I'm also new to this :)

Comment: ^ Yeah I am looking through variables stored in the LinkedList<vehicle> and yeah how do I do that? Sorry, I'm still really new to java

Answer (score 0):

AAAAAAAND I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT TOGETHER WITH MY OTHER FRIEND
Still, I'd love to thank all of you for extending a hand to help me :')

Shall post the solution to my problem here

```
//-etc-
   // Create readers to read from user input
    //FileReader ufr = new FileReader(INPUT_PROMPT);
    BufferedReader ubr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

   // Read one line from user input
   String uline=ubr.readLine();
    // Loop through all the records in the LinkedList


    for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++)
    {
    // if the record is the same as the input from user 
    // (Hint: use contains() in String class to check whether 
    // search word is found in the records

     Vehicle vehicle = list.get(i);

    if(vehicle.group.contains(uline) || 
       vehicle.brand.contains(uline) ||
       vehicle.model.contains(uline))
    {
        //print out the information of the vehicle that match user input
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

    }
```